# Changing typeface of textview upon selecting an item in expandable list view

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview, typeface

I have an `expandable list view` comprising of `textview` and `imageview` as parent and `textview` as child. Is there a way to set `typeface` of `textview`(either in parent or child layout) based upon the selection made?
I want to change `typeface` to `bold` when a user selects an item from the list. I searched a lot but we have only group `click` or `child click listeners`. `getSelectedItem()` or `getSelectedItemPosition()` doesn't give appropriate result. Please suggest

Comment: add the code where you implemented listener for click on the child items of the list view

Answer (score 0):

1) you can check `expListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)`  and provide conditions for changing typeface accordingly.

2) you can also do it like this :

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                                int groupPosition, long id) {

                        if(parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
                        {

                         // Do your Staff
                        }
                        else{

                           // Expanded ,Do your Staff

                        }


                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

3) you can do it in `getGroupView` just check the boolean `isGroupExpanded` and do your stuff.

Comment: This will give access to only those groups which have children. But i want to change text style of all the groups on clicking